# phpDocumentor2: XSLT not found

Tags: php, xslt, phpdoc

if i call the phpDocumentor to generate a documentation all works fine until the XSLT-Transformation begins. Then i get following message:

```
[phpDocumentor\Plugin\Core\Exception]
The XSL writer was unable to find your XSLTProcessor; please check if you have 
installed the PHP XSL extension
```

That's very confusing cause the **XSLT Support** for PHP is installed & **is activated**. Here is a screenshot of the PHP-Information via Debian Terminal:

```
xsl
XSL => enabled
libxslt Version => 1.1.26
libxslt compiled against libxml Version => 2.7.7
EXSLT => enabled
libexslt Version => 1.1.26
```

The Environment:

- Apache 2
- PHP 5.3.3 (php5-cli / xslt-support installed later)
- Zend-Server with Zend Engine 2
- phpDocumentor2 (Pear installation)

Anyone has an idea what the problems are?

Answer (score 0):

Finally i could locate and solve the problem:

The Problem were the extensions loaded by the CLI-PHP.ini.

I solved the problem by copying all extensions (and their interfaces) to the same directories. All extensions together in 1 directory (and all interfaces together in their directory) within the Zend-filestructure.

Then i put symbolic links into the CLI-config directory *(/etc/php5/cli/)* targeting to this extension directory *(usr/local/zend/lib/php_extension)* to specify which extensions(*.so) are available(!) but the interfaces (*.ini) to use the extension i put into default php5-extension directory *(/etc/php5/conf.d/)* and noticed that in the CLI-php.ini. This reduces the extensions used by CLI (that "double-included" some extensions).

Finally i activated the XSLT-Extension by copying the interface (not the extension) into php5-default extension directory *(/etc/php5/conf.d/)*.

Now all PHP5x Configurations on our system can use the same extensions which are placed only once within the system. And it works very fine now.

I hope this will help someone.